# Excel 2007 - Compare two sheets and paste the variance in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets named sheet1 and sheet2 ; Both have same number of columns which started from A to AI . I need to compare both the sheets if in-case it finds variance in anyone of the individual cell on that time it must to copy the entire row and paste it into new sheet named Sheet3. Kindly reply me as soon as possible.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code so we can improve it. This isn't the sort of place that does your work for you by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I need to write it from the scratch .. Is it possible to compare and paste the variance in new sheet ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick pseudocode sample of how I would go about it:

```
for each row in worksheet
  for each cell in the row
    if cell on sheet1 <> cell on sheet2
      copy row to sheet3
    end if
  next
next
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, I've been trying to find something similar, but will this only point out differences or will it copy cell-by-cell changes only? For example, if I have 1000 rows and someone deletes row 2 then I would only want to know that row 2 is gone; as opposed to the macro copying everything from row 2 to the end because the macro is seeing that every row from 2 onwards has changed.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jon: how would the macro know that row2 was deleted rather than edited? You'd have to put more constraints on the code it you wanted to be able to reliably detect deleted rows (eg. there would have to be at least one cell in each row which could be relied on to be unique and static)

Comment: Well, i think that's what I was trying to get at Tim.  Granted I am trying to learn this stuff at the same time, but I was reading that the op was asking about finding variance between individual cells; then when I look at Craig's code I'm reading, unless I am wrong :), that any row with any change will be copied to a third sheet.  So, if the op had two sheets and the recent version had, for example, Row 2 deleted out then the recent report would likely have moved all cells up one row...

Comment: which then means that every row in the sheet may match the old data exactly, but because each cell has changed all of the data would get copied over to his third sheet as a "variance."

Comment: unless you have some sort of ID key on each line, then this is exactly what would happen. The question is asking for a direct comparison of the two sheets, if a row is deleted then all rows after that will likely not match.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options

You can download a 30 free trial version of [SpreadSheet Advantage](http://www.spreadsheetadvantage.com/) which has a

1) column and row alignment function that can be run to set the 2 sheets up in a like for like fashion (to adjust for a deleted or additional row as per Tom's point above).

2) A very quick sheet v sheet compare output that works on **formulae, values or both**, highlighting only the parts of the cells that are different

or

If the sheets are already perfectly aligned

- you could use this free [compare.xla](http://www.cpearson.com/Zips/Compare.zip) addin by Myrna Lawson and Bill Manville
- if you wanted a **value comparison only** then you could set up a simple formula in A1 of a third sheet to compare the values of A1 in sheets 1 and 2 etc